# Rails 4 Routing conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am rewritting a rails app I did some 5 years ago using rails 1.something.
When I try to browse localhost/companies/search_updates/ I get this error... I know this is a routing error because when I remove the resources :companies from router.rb the thing works fine... How can this be fixed? And do I need to manually add routes for every action I create?

Error when I try to access localhost/companies/search_updates/

```
The action 'show' could not be found for CompaniesController
```

Controler

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @companies = Company.all
  end
  def search_updates
    # Execute code to search for updates
    # Redirect to results
  end
end
```

Routes

```
resources :accounts
resources :companies
get 'companies/search_updates' =>   'companies#search_updates'
```

search_updates.html.erb

```
Hello Updates!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`The action 'show' could not be found for CompaniesController`

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you
>   have a resources :companies above a get 'companies/search_updates' the show action's
>   route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To
>   fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is
>   matched first.

```
resources :accounts
get 'companies/search_updates' =>   'companies#search_updates'
resources :companies
```

And

> Resource routing allows you to quickly declare all of the common
>   routes for a given resourceful controller. Instead of declaring
>   separate routes for your index, show, new, edit, create, update and
>   destroy actions, a resourceful route declares them in a single line of
>   code.

If you have only index method (default CURD rails) on your controller, you can specific routes for it.

```
resources :accounts
get 'companies/search_updates' =>   'companies#search_updates'
resources :companies, :only => [index]
```

Comment: this solved it ty... but tell me more.  Do I need to manually add every route or  is there some too to do it automatically?

Comment: In your case, yes. But in rails have generator (scaffold) for automatically CURD, scaffold in Rails is a full set of model, database migration for that model, controller to manipulate it, views to view and manipulate the data, and a test suite for each of the above. ref : [source 1](rails generate) [source 2](http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/scaffold_anlegen.html)